# Unity - Android 10 - BLE Bluetooth - Background location

Tags: android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am working on a Unity Android project where I use bluetooth scanning service. I started having problems in bluetooth connection when I upgraded to Android 10 (API 29). I am taking help from this post (link below) where it mentions that with Android 10 onwards one needs to include the `BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission.

[Android 10 not working with BLE Bluetooth scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428763/android-10-not-working-with-ble-bluetooth-scanning)

In Unity, I have written some code using a permission utility tool

```
  if (AndroidRuntimePermissions.CheckPermission(Permission.CoarseLocation) != AndroidRuntimePermissions.Permission.Granted)
  {
      AndroidRuntimePermissions.RequestPermission(Permission.CoarseLocation);   
  }
```

`Permission` class is an internal class from `UnityEngine.Android` which does not seem to have background location permission. See below,

```
using UnityEngine.Scripting;

/// <summary>
///   <para>Structure describing a permission that requires user authorization.</para>
/// </summary>
[NativeHeader ("Runtime/Export/Android/AndroidPermissions.bindings.h")]
[UsedByNativeCode]
public struct Permission
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>Used when requesting permission or checking if permission has been granted to use the camera.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public const string Camera = "android.permission.CAMERA";

    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>Used when requesting permission or checking if permission has been granted to use the microphone.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public const string Microphone = "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO";

    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>Used when requesting permission or checking if permission has been granted to use the users location with high precision.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public const string FineLocation = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION";

    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>Used when requesting permission or checking if permission has been granted to use the users location with coarse granularity.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public const string CoarseLocation = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION";

    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>Used when requesting permission or checking if permission has been granted to read from external storage such as a SD card.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public const string ExternalStorageRead = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";

    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>Used when requesting permission or checking if permission has been granted to write to external storage such as a SD card.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public const string ExternalStorageWrite = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";

    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>Check if the user has granted access to a device resource or information that requires authorization.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="permission">A string representing the permission to request. For permissions which Unity has not predefined you may also manually provide the constant value obtained from the Android documentation here: https:developer.android.comguidetopicspermissionsoverview#permission-groups such as "android.permission.READ_CONTACTS".</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///   <para>Whether the requested permission has been granted.</para>
    /// </returns>
    [MethodImpl (MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    [StaticAccessor ("PermissionsBindings", StaticAccessorType.DoubleColon)]
    public static extern bool HasUserAuthorizedPermission (string permission);

    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>Request that the user grant access to a device resource or information that requires authorization.</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="permission">A string that describes the permission to request. For permissions which Unity has not predefined you may also manually provide the constant value obtained from the Android documentation here: https:developer.android.comguidetopicspermissionsoverview#permission-groups such as "android.permission.READ_CONTACTS".</param>
    [MethodImpl (MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    [StaticAccessor ("PermissionsBindings", StaticAccessorType.DoubleColon)]
    public static extern void RequestUserPermission (string permission);
}
```

Please let me know if you have got your way around this problem. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a string so pass the permission class that you want into it.

```
 Permission.RequestUserPermission( "android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" );
```

I used this to ensure I get all three options for location permission request ("alway", "only when open", "never")

Comment: Thanks for your help. Also, Android 10 needs the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission along with the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION